# .Net Framework installation include MSBuild?

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration

I'm writing my first CI script using *MSBuild* and I want to everyone that have a machine with the *.Net Framework* can download my project and do a *build/publish* operations executing only one `.cmd/.bat` file.

Then I'm putting in the repository dependencies libs to *build/publish* this project.

I need to put msbuild.exe in the repository too? Or MSBuild come together with *.Net Framework* installation?

Note: I'm *building/publishing* a web project and using `_WPPCopyWebApplication` target of this DLL: `Microsoft.WebApplication.Build.Tasks.Dll`. I need to copy this dll to my repository too like this: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/05/30/msbuild-and-web-application-projects.aspx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put MSBuild into source control repository. It is installed as part of .NET (Full Framework, not just Client Profile), you don't need SDK.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting in .Net 2.0, MSBuild is part of the framework. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/25/the-visual-studio-blog.aspx

It is located in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe (for .net version 3.5)