# Difference in compiled EXE Windows desktop application between Visual C# Express and Visual C# Professional

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, compilation, visual-c#-express-2010

Is it possible to develop in C# a desktop application for windows in Visual Studio 2013 Community and the compile it with Visual C# 2012 Express for desktop application?

What is the difference in exe application compiled with Visual C# 2012 Express it the application source is developed in:

- Visual C# Express 2012
- Visual C# 2013 Community for desktop
- Visual Studio 2012 Professional

Can someone tell from compiled exe application in which development tool the application have been build and compiled?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that it is possible to determine the Visual Studio edition or version based on the compiled exe/dll, but I do not have any hard proof for that. However, a huge hint in that direction is that you do need to have install any version of Visual Studio in order to compile a simple sln or csproj. As long as the correct version of the .NET Framework is installed, you can always just invoke  MSBuild directly (ie. `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe MySolution.sln`). MSBuild and the C# compiler (`csc`) are [included in the .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558236/11963).